# Using Visio to document access databases?

Tags: database, documentation, microsoft-visio-2007

I'm using Visio to create diagrams of a number of Access databases, using the Database->Reverse Engineer option.

Do I have to create an ODBC connection for each access file, or is there a quicker way to do it?